# I'm getting a linker error I don't understand with VC++ and FLTK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fltk

I'm trying to create a new project with FLTK and VC++2010. I haven't done this in a while. I set up the properties by memory as best I could. I'm getting a linker error though. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BJST chap 14 ex 1a, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ 
1>  BJST chap 14 ex 1.cpp 
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1.cpp(10): error C2065: 'FL_Window' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1.cpp(10): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'window'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1.cpp(10): error C3861: 'window': identifier not found
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1.cpp(12): error C2065: 'FL_Box' : undeclared identifier 
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'box'
1>c:\users\bryan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1a\bjst chap 14 ex 1.cpp(12): error C3861: 'box': identifier not found 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== 


#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>



int main ()
{

    FL_Window window(200, 200, "window title");

    FL_Box box();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'missing ';' before identifier 'box'` isn't a **linker** error!

Comment: Did you forget `#include <FLTK_header_name_goes_here.h>`? Or maybe the FLTK types belong to some namespace, and you need to qualify them. Anyway, none of those are linker errors.

Comment: I"m using box and window and you can see they are both included.

Comment: Missed a `namespace` maybe?

Comment: Got it. FL_Window needs to be Fl_Window, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This error message

> error C2065: 'FL_Window' : undeclared identifier

means that the compiler did not find the declaration of identifier `FL_Window`. it is posiible (and I think that it is indeed so) that this name is declared in some namespace provided that you typed it correctly. Check header file  `<FL/Fl_Window.H>` whether this name is declared in some namespace. In this case you have to write at least as

```
TheNameSpace::FL_Window window(200, 200, "window title");
```

where instead of `TheNameSpace` write the namespace where name `FL_Window` is declared.

It seems that there is also the same problem with identifier `FL_Box`

Comment: Spot on. BTW, FLTK1 has no name-space... FLTK2 does.